# Подскажите, в чем смысл аргументов функции?

Tags: haskell

Есть функция

```
rtct::String->Bool->[(String,Bool)]->Bool
rtct a b xd= foldr (\(q,yn) c -> c||((a==q)&&(b/=yn))) (False) xd
```

Свертка foldr принимает бинарную функцию, начальное значение и список, а здесь у бинарной функции аргументы кортеж и с, как это понимать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос не понятен. Параметр rtct и, соответсвенно, foldr -- список кортежей, у бинарной функции -- кортеж (из этого списка). Вашу функцию можно переписать как

```
rtct a b xd = any (\(q, yn) -> a == q && b /= yn) xd
```

Или, убирая xd

```
rtct a b = any (\(q, yn) -> a == q && b /= yn)
```

Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.

**upd**
Попробуем так:
тип фунции foldr:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

В Вашем случае параметр типа *a* обозначает тип (String, Bool), а параметр типа *b* -- тип Bool (соответственно по типам всё нормально). Функция, используемая в foldr применяется к элементам списка (список -- [(String, Bool)], элемент -- (String, Bool) ) и к аккумулятору типа Bool.